# Wordpress => Get the post categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm currently trying to get the categories when I create a post. For exemple here I want to create a post with the category ' actus ' and ' sport ' : [image]

But then, when I want to get the category in PHP, I do :

```
$categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
```

Then for testing I do :

```
echo $categories[0]->name
```

But this is giving me Uncategorized as value, but I haven't selected this category in the post.

Am I using the wrong solution to get a specific post categories when he is created ?

The best result would be an array of string with the categories names

This is all my code :

```
function new_post($post_id, $post, $update) {
  if ($post->post_status == 'publish' && empty(get_post_meta( $post_id, 'check_if_run_once' ))) {

    $client = new \Fcm\FcmClient(
       apiKey,
       id
    );

    $notification = new \Fcm\Push\Notification();

    $fcmData = [
      'dataTitle' => $post->post_title,
      "path" => "/la-baleine-de-retour-en-mariniere-sur-le-front-de-mer-darcachon",
    ];

    $terms = join( '', wp_list_pluck( wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'category' ), 'name' ) );


    $notification
      ->addTopic('actus')
      ->setTitle("Un nouvel article est disponible: ")
      ->setBody($terms)
      ->addDataArray($fcmData);

    $response = $client->send($notification);

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'check_if_run_once', true );
  }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'new_post', 10, 3);
```

Comment: If you haven't selected a category, you'd get the default post category (which is normally 'Uncategorized') Try changing your default post category and see if it changes what you get returned.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, i'm selecting 2 categories

Comment: I see the screenshot. What's less clear is when you're calling the function and when you're expecting the categories to exist. People are trying to help you out for free on the Internet try for some level of manners.

Answer (score 0):

Categories are only applied to a post upon publishing/update. You would need to capture them after submitting using the `save_post` action hook.

```php
<?php

add_action( 'save_post', function( $post_id, $post ) {

$terms = join( '', wp_list_pluck( wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'category' ), 'name' ) );

// ...

}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I have edited my post with all my function. Using your solution, I still have "Uncategorized" as value for $terms

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

For anyone wondering, "save_post" or "publish_post" actions are triggered before setting of the terms.

You have to use " wp_after_insert_post " instead

Comment: Can you show how did you use the said function?